# mysql - String not assuming empty default after upgrade

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, mysql-5.7, wamp3

I recently updated my MySQL (and wamp to v3) and moved my old databases there.

Previously, field types such as varchar, char, text, etc would assume a default value of empty string if no value was given (even though I had no explicitly set this default while  creating the table structure ).

But after the update when I try to run my previously working code, it gives me exceptions that

> Field `<field_name>` doesn't have a default value

I'm guessing this is a setting in mysql or something. can anyone help me out?

thanks.

Comment: I think you have `not null` option applied right?

Comment: yes. but not null string fields were defaulting to empty string previously.

Comment: yes it's just a configuration

Comment: MYSQL 5.7 has had some serious changes made in this area. You had better take some time to review the [Changes Affecting Upgrades to MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out strict mode was enabled.

disabled strict mode by changing the line

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

to

```
sql-mode=""
```

reference: https://support.kayako.com/article/472-how-do-i-disable-mysql-strict-mode-on-the-server

Comment: To configure using SQL, use `mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"` to get settings and `mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'yourmodifiedsettingshere';"` to set them.